# What should I look for in camera phone specs to ensure quick focus?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, autofocus, focus

I have been searching for good camera phone. I am looking for two things:

**Good/Quick Focus:**
I have used `Nokia X2 DS`, camera phone in this phone rear camera takes too much time to focus on a scene and until then it remains blur. E.g.: I put on my camera I wait for 4-5 seconds for getting its focus, now without clicking I start moving towards picture and I  lost focus I wait again to get focus again. This issue is always re-producible inside room and when there is low light, but intermittent in good-light/sun-light.

What I want is quick clicking of nice pictures? Which feature should I look for in camera phones?

Comment: Many phones do not need to focus. In the spec, it usually says *Fixed focus lens*.

Answer (score 1):

> So which feature should I look for if I want good quality zoomed videos/pictures?

**Lens with Optical Zoom**.
Smartphones do not generally have it except a few like Galaxy Camera.

> which feature in camera called which gives quick focus?

**Phase Detection Auto Focus**.
It is very rare in smartphones, Pixel XL is an example.
Moto G4 Plus is another example in mid-range.

It is difficult to extract any more information from specifications because of how boastful OEMs are and because they are generally not doing any practical comparisons with anything else. Make your judgmenet based on trusted review sources.

Comment: The Pixel XL if no others have PDAF elements on the sensor.

Comment: Maybe I didnt put question in better words but what I meant to ask is: If there are two many phones claiming they have `optical zoom` and `auto focus`, what is the measurement/degree I would see on the box/manual, how does professionals chose a good camera. E.g. Motorcycles have good pick up ranging from 15-18 bhp, so you know 18 is good, 15 is poor and 16bhp between good and bad. so In above example `Moto G4 Plus` `what is its degree of Good zoom and auto focus?` I mean why I can't stick to LeEco Le2 instead of purchasing new Moto G4 plus

Comment: @paul: I cannot estalish a science with these terms. The definition of a tolerable picture is non-existent, there are drastically different requirements for different use cases. Moto G4 does not have optical zoom. Smartphone cameras are compromises and I can only say that much about choosing between them as I said in my answer.

Comment: @paul: My personal stance is DO NOT USE A SMARTPHONE TO TAKE PHOTOS. For me every camera with sensor smaller than 2/3" is the same. Clearly it is different for you but I do not know your requirements and I have almost zero experience with smartphone photography.

Comment: @EuriPinhollow You are right, I totally buy what you are saying. It's just that I want to know that jargon/slang that pro cameramen see in to measure from `bad zoom` to `good zoom` quality and from bad `auto-focus` to good `auto-focus`. E.g. I have 3 cameras (leave phone camera or actual camera)  3mp, 5mp and 13mp do I totally rely that 13mp would have better zoom quality. If yes, can we measure late/quick focus in some way, if yes what is that measuring unit/degree?

Comment: @paul: we probably can but please do it without me. :) There is a number of techniques for characterising focusing speed but it does not matter because almost any mention of focusing speed will be informal like "fast", "tolerable" etc. I have mentioned two properties of a camera which can more or less mean that the zooming quality is good and that focusing speed is good. Yes there are cameras with somewhat good digital (non-optical) zoom. Yes there are cameras with somewhat good focusing speed even without phase detection. However, to see if they're fine you need to research each one.

Comment: iPhone 6 and later also have on-sensor PDAF, though they call it "focus pixels".  Most modern smartphone cameras probably do as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to https://www.dxomark.com/Mobiles where they compare smartphone camera specs rates individual specification(camera features).
instagram/lumiadiaries

Comment: Can you please provide some example about those specifications

Answer (score 0):

Personally, one of the biggest factors deciding focusing speed would be the lens Aperture, wider the aperture the more light allowed in the lens, this would help in all shooting scenarios, especially in low light levels. The LG G4 has one of the lowest apertures currently.